# My Code seems to be inefficient and provokes jdbc Exceptions

Tags: java, database, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing out Data from HTML files and writing them to a database. 
It worked until 10 Minutes ago, when suddenly more and more exceptions popped up when running the java workflow. I already tried this: `set @@global.max_connections = 1250;` Here is an example of the error:

```
Jul 21, 2014 4:22:58 PM org.jsoup.examples.Database OpenConnectionDB
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.examples.Database.OpenConnectionDB(Database.java:34)
    at org.jsoup.examples.Database.insert(Database.java:67)
    at org.jsoup.examples.parseEasy.getData(parseEasy.java:61)
    at org.jsoup.examples.parseEasy.main(parseEasy.java:30)
```

The (wall of) code i'm executing is here. Maybe someone of you has a good eye for the mistake I make here. I can't figure it out, and I don't expect anyone to search through it. Just if someone immediatelly knows, where the mistake originates, I would be happy to hear it. Thank you!

```
package org.jsoup.examples;

import java.io.*;   

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class parseEasy {



        static parseEasy parseIt = new parseEasy();

        String companyName = "Platzhalter";
        String jobTitle = "Platzhalter";
        String location = "Platzhalter";
        String timeAdded = "Platzhalter";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Database connect = new Database();
        connect.OpenConnectionDB();

        parseIt.getData();

        connect.closeConnectionDB();


    }

    // 
    public void getData() throws IOException 
    {
        Database c = new Database();

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/keywords_Medizin.txt"), "utf-8");
        Elements elements = document.select(".joblisting");
        for (Element element : elements) 
        {
            // Counter for Number of Elements returned


            // Parse Data into Elements
            Elements jobTitleElement = element.select(".job_title span");
            Elements companyNameElement = element.select(".company_name span[itemprop=name]");
            Elements locationElement = element.select(".locality span[itemprop=addressLocality]");
            Elements dateElement = element.select(".job_date_added [datetime]");

            // Strip Data from unnecessary tags
            String companyName = companyNameElement.text();
            String jobTitle = jobTitleElement.text();
            String location = locationElement.text();
            String timeAdded = dateElement.attr("datetime");

            c.insert(companyName, jobTitle, timeAdded, location);



            // Test output
            //System.out.println("Firma:\t"+ companyName + "\t" + jobTitle + "\t in:\t" + location + " \t Erstellt am \t" + timeAdded + "\t. Eintrag Nummer:\t" + count);

        }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Too many connections.

Comment: Why are you creating a new database in `getData()` ?

Comment: Im quite new to programming. I think i couldn't reference it from some static context? Hm, any ideas how to fix it? Thanks guys so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing the connections to the database. One reason is that you create two instances of `Database`. The one in `main()` is closed but the second one in `getData()` isn't.

Note that you should close the database in a `finally` block to make sure the connection is closed even when there is an exception.

To reuse the database connection change

```
parseIt.getData();
```

to

```
parseIt.getData(connect);
```

and

```
public void getData() throws IOException
```

to

```
public void getData(Database c) throws IOException
```

Comment: Sorry, one question concerning the two instances: Is there a way to work with just one? I get the "static reference to a non-static...." error if I try to work with connect( Database Instance invoked before)?

Comment: Why don't you pass the instance from `main()` to `getData()` as a parameter?

Comment: can you give me a short example? As I said, Im new to this and examples make me learn best. You helped great so far. It now runs smootly, but longer

Comment: See my edits how to pass a local variable to a method.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.